# javascript manifest file for standalone html app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, gruntjs, bower

I am building a web application where the backend exposes a REST API.  The web UI should use the REST API and change the view accordingly.  So the UI is full of normal html and javascript files.

For every javascript/css file that I create, I have to add a corresponding line in the html file.  Is there anyway I can make this task easier.  Like having a manifest file which allows me to include whole directories.  (Similar to rails' application.js file)

I will then include only this manifest file in my html and all the files listed in the manifest should be included dynamically.  But when I deploy, all these files should be concatenated and minified.  Is this possible?

My web server is nginx.  I am using grunt for my build and bower to manage dependencies.

Comment: Would it be a solution to concatenate the files? That would work well for performance as well.

Comment: Add all of your js files into one `app.js` file or something, and then you only need to call one file.